# Is this wall load bearing? Blueprint attached

Tags: structural

There was a partition wall added to close to where the blue line is.
The original blueprint looks like there may have been a wall.

Is it a load bearing wall?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any other plans such as for roof trusses

Comment: Which direction do floor joists go?

Comment: image needs more detail

Answer (score 1):

The drawing is a bit hard to read.

However it appears what you have marked with a blue line is noting a beam.

3 x 3x10 spanning the outside concrete block walls.  ( those are noted as having to be load bearing)

Any load bearing wall in a drawing will be prominently noted. There is **no** type of wall drawn where you have your blue line.